# Share a board in realtime to teach chess

Tags: online-chess, chessboards, online

A user of our community with solid experience in the game wants to teach others. There is a video broadcast in our site. I need to attach a shareable chessboard to the broadcast. Where a coach can manipulate with figures and students can see the changes simultaneously.

Is there any online service which allow to share a board in real time (I suppose to show it in a frame)?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any online service which allow to share a board in real time
>   (I suppose to show it in a frame)?

Have you tried sharing your desktop in a Skype conference call?

Another alternative might be Google+.

Answer (score 4):

Lichess has a feature called "study" which allows collaboration and best of all it is free: https://en.lichess.org/blog/V0KrLSkAAMo3hsi4/study-chess-the-lichess-way

Comment: This works really well for live streaming an in person match too. I set up a camera showing the players and the board and then a Picture-in-Picture window (using ATEM Mini Pro) of a web browser showing the Lichess study board. I entered the actual moves into the "main" Lichess Study board using my phone and they show up almost instantaneously on the remote browser and live stream.

Answer (score 0):

Chess.com live chess last this feature. However, I think you should be premium member for that.